# Scrapy site redirects to 404 after loading

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, http-status-code-404, splash-screen

I am trying to crawl a fashion site, however, when i try to render the page that I want to crawl from the scrapy shell, I will see it loading the page first then redirects it to 404 page.
This is the command that I ran

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.108 Safari/537.36' 'http://www.asos.com/search/circle%20skirt?currentpricerange=10-95&q=circle%20skirt&refine=attribute_900:1573'
```

I tried adding headers and cookies as well, but nothing seem to work, the page keeps redirecting to 404. What should I do?

Comment: if page uses relative url then when browser renders it then HTML and javascript try to read data from your computer and it can't get expected data. But if you display `repsonse.body` then you may see different content.

Comment: `repsonse.body` may have all what you need - so open url in browser manually to see all tags in `DevTool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution, as furas commented, the response.body had all the things that i needed, the only reason view(response) was not working cause the site required to load JS stuff and that caused the 404. Thanks for the help furas